# Web service running constantly and Tomcat app displays results

Tags: java, tomcat, ping, dashboard, response-time

-I built a dashboard to monitor the response time of different URLs; in the splash page you get a list of these URLs along with their response times. The response times refresh every 60 seconds automatically.

It is a Tomcat application where the pinging of the URLs is obviously done on the Java side. The issue is that, the way it works right now, those URLs will only be pinged when the application is opened on the browser. But what I really need is for them to be pinged constantly in the background in a (web?) service -every 60 seconds-, and then when someone pulls up the dashboard (UI) it shows what the current status of all the URLs is. So the heavy lifting would be done by the service that pings the URLs and then the UI basically 'connects' to the service.

I thought about having a JAR run in the background, which would ping the sites but then how would I connect from the UI to the JAR? It needs to work seamlessly, real time. I need a way to merge the two channels (the service making the calls and the UI)

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: do you mean asynchronous call to a service ?

Comment: It doesn't necessarily have to do with synchronization. I want to have a service running constantly that calculates response times for these URLs every minute. And then when someone goes into the web application they can see what the current response time is for every URL. So I need to be able to see the calculated results from the UI @RafikBELDI